# Need Web service for Google Fit API?

Tags: android, web-services, google-api, google-fit

I'm designing to develop a java predicting application by analyzing the Human movements.
To get inputs I'm planing to use Google Fitness API.
*But I'm unfamiliar with fitness api.*

**Do I need to have a web service to collect and store the data from Google Fitness API?**

Can Someone describe about pre-requirement of the Fit API?

Answer (score 0):

You can go through the tutorial:

[Google Fit - REST API](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/)